# Add Element inside of an element XML VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

How can I add an element inside of another element. Im sure this is easy but I cant seem to find an answer in vb.net. I pretty much need a file that looks like:

```
<Crop>
     <Name>CropName</Name>
     <Field>
        <Name>FieldName</Name>
           <Expense>
              <expense1></expense1>
              <expense2></expense2>
           </Expense>
     </Field>
</Crop
<Crop>
     <Name>CropName1</Name>
     <Field>
        <Name>FieldName</Name>
           <Expense>
              <expense1></expense1>
              <expense2></expense2>
           </Expense>
     </Field>
</Crop
```

I also need help adding to this. So lets say I want to add to the crop called 'CropName1' and add another field element like I already have inside 'CropName1' then how would I do that in vb.net. I am open to use linq or whatever. Example code would be great help. Please don't give me a link to a tutorial on LINQ and xml. I know how XML works just not sure how to do this particular problem and thought I could get some sample code from you all. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything? `XElement` constructor has `params` argument which allows you to include content for given element. There is also a method called `Add` on `XElement` class, which you can use to modify existing elements (e.g. after retrieving them by LINQ to XML query). You should probably start with that. In current form I think your question is too broad to get a good answer (as I agree that link to LINQ to XML tutorial is not a good answer).

Comment: Yes I have done a lot of playing around but I can't figure out a loop that will work. All i can do is add an element to existing file but I can't seem to add one inside an element.

Comment: At least post initial XML and the output XML you expect. Will be better if you can post closest attempt you've tried so we can explain what was wrong and possibly suggest something to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I like using [XML literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384629.aspx) and [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) when dealing with XML in VB.NET.

Here is a simple example:

```vb
' Create the root XElement
Dim xml = <Crops></Crops>
' Add a couple of <Crop>s, substituting the value of i into the names
For i = 0 To 1
    xml.Add(
        <Crop>
            <Name>CropName<%= i %></Name>
            <Field>
                <Name>FieldName</Name>
                <Expense>
                    <expense1></expense1>
                    <expense2></expense2>
                </Expense>
            </Field>
        </Crop>
    )
Next
' Find the <Crop> element that contains <Name>CropName1</Name>
Dim crop1 = (From c In xml...<Crop> Where c.<Name>.Value = "CropName1").SingleOrDefault()
' Insert a new <Field> element
If crop1 IsNot Nothing Then
    crop1.Add(
        <Field>
            <Name>FieldName2</Name>
            <Expense>
                <expense1></expense1>
                <expense2></expense2>
            </Expense>
        </Field>
    )
End If
```